# Facebook like webpage button description

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I see the webpage title, link, image, but I cannot get any description. My client want's a describing text when a user has clicked like on the webpage. Is this not possible??

I had to use the old way of sharing since the new doesn't work together with the other things on the site.

I have ran it through the Facebook Debugger and the only problem it states is:

```
Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed:

Parser Mismatched Metadata: The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input property =>content pairs that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:description => the site desc'
```

However I think this is only because I use `<meta name="description">` as well. Because it does fetch and display this information in the debugger:

```
Raw Open Graph Document Information

Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:url" content="http://website.nu/" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image" content="http://website.nu/img/img200x200.jpg" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:title" content="website title" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:site_name" content="site_name" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="fb:admins" content="[my fb id]" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:description" content="site desc" />
```

### Website source code:

```
<head>  
    <meta name="description" content="Page description">

    <meta property="og:url" content="http://website.nu/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://website.nu/img/img_200x200.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Site title"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>    
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site name"/> 
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="[my_fb_id]"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Page description, expected to output"/>    
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://website.nu/index.php/&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=90&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:94px; height:20px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the <meta name="description"> tag after the <meta property="og:description"> tag.

Answer (score 0):

The og:description needs to be after the og:image property.
At least that was working for me.
description after og:description or removing the description-metatag didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

try to [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) your content for example:

```
echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . trim($content) . '"/>';
```